# AES Encrypt DMG for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, macos, dmg-image, aes

I need to encrypt a dmg file with an AES key. On MAC we can do so on Disk Utilities but how to do it on Windows?

I tried Mac Tools Lite but it has no such function. I also tried Google Search but I could only find ways to open and decrypt DMgs.

Comment: Was it you who asked [How Can I Encrypt DMG File On Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/917562/how-can-i-encrypt-dmg-file-on-windows) recently?

Comment: No. Pure coincidence.